# CMake target_link_libraries converting path which results in linker "not found" error

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake to build a module for an external application. As part of the build, I'm also generating an executable which links against the module to run tests. However as part of module convention for the external application, the module name should not have the `lib` prefix. This results in the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(mymodule SHARED mymodule.c)
set_target_properties(mymodule PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

add_executable(mytest mytest.c)
target_link_libraries(mytest ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mymodule.so)
```

When building, CMake is converting the path to a search name, which results in the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmymodule
```

If I run `cmake .` again (without changing anything) after `mymodule.so` is built, it switches from using `-lmymodule` to the actual path of `mymodule.so`, and it works. If I remove the `PROPERTIES PREFIX ""`, it also works.

Since I'm specifying the `mymodule.so` path within `target_link_libraries()`, how can I get CMake to stop converting it into search name (`-lmymodule`)?

Comment: Why don't you use the target name in the first place? `target_link_libraries(mytest mymodule)`

Comment: @ixSci Well that was stupidly simple. Did that and it worked. I think I had started using the path instead of the name due to a previous issue that I was having, and I never changed it back. If you want to drop that as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should link against targets, not files if those targets are part of your project. In your case it would be `target_link_libraries(mytest mymodule)`.

But if for some reason the need arises to link against a full path, CMake has some peculiarities which are described in the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#id3). So in your case it converts the full path to `-lmymodule` because it is a behavior CMake exhibits if the full path provided to the library w/o proper [soname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname).